# Socket.io sends back multiple responses only to the sender

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

so I wanted to dive into Socket.io and I am a complete beginner in it. I am a react developer and decided to test it with react, this is my client side:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
function App() {
  let [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  let [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const socket = io("http://localhost:4000/", {
    withCredentials: true,
    cors: {
      origin: "http://localhost:4000",
    },
  });

  const sendMessage = (msg) => {
    socket.emit("messageToServer", msg);
  };
  socket.on("messageToClient", (msg) => {
    setMessages((prevMessage) => prevMessage.concat(msg));
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {messages}

      <input
        id="input"
        autoComplete="off"
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => sendMessage(message)}>Send</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this is my server side(Node, Express):

```
const app = require("express")();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  let messages = [];
  socket.on("messageToServer", (msg) => {
    io.emit("messageToClient", msg);
    console.log(msg);
  });
});

http.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("listening on *:3000");
});
```

So basicly when I write something on the input and click the button, on the node server everything seems fine and the message logs only once, but when I open the tab that I send the message from and for example I typed 'First message' it will print something like: 'First messageFirst messageFirst messageFirst message' and so on...
But apparently, the duplication is happening only from the tab I am sending it from, because when I open a new one and test it, on the sender tab I get multiple like i said, but on the new one, I recieve it only one, just like it should be.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below snippet of code will keep App component being rendered multiple times, thus the same event handler for `messageToClient` will be registered multiple times and cause unexpected behavior in React.

```
  socket.on("messageToClient", (msg) => {
    setMessages((prevMessage) => prevMessage.concat(msg));
  });
```

You should wrap socket on event with `useEffect`, so that we can make sure nothing is duplicating.

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    socket.on("messageToClient", (msg) => {
      setMessages((prevMessage) => prevMessage.concat(msg));
    });
    
    // unbind the event handler when the component gets unmounted
    return () => {
      socket.off('messageToClient')
    }
  },[])
```

Comment: Ohh, I see! Thanks for taking the time to explain, it worked!